# SQL CE and heavy load - performance?

Tags: sql, performance

I am considering using SQL CE for multithreaded server where there is at approx. 80 clients often (secs) working with data in DB. I know MySQL (EDIT: unoffical servers) has no problems (World of Warcraft speaks for itself), but what about that?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought WoW runs on Oracle

Comment: Sorry, I meant unoffical servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a server, I would recommend SQL Server Express Edition - I have used it on a server with higher loads than you mention with no problem.  Is there a reason you are using SQL CE?  To my knowledge, SQL CE is recommended primarily for embedded apps and on handheld devices where you cannot use a full server-edition product.

Comment: OK, also many threads asking at the same time is no problem? I am afraid whether it would not cause lags.

Comment: Not with a database.  They're designed to handle things like that - that's probably their primary advantage over using a flat file.